# Inefficient .Net fork/join

Tags: java, .net, multithreading

I've implemented a parallel mergesort using Java fork/join pool and .Net Parallel.Invoke, and I observe  drmamatic difference in perofmance between the versions: 5 sec (Java) and 45 sec (.Net) to sort a 2GB file. That's almost order of magnitude difference.

Here's the .Net code:

```
    public void ParallelSort()
    {
        Start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        int lo = 0;
        int hi = values.Length - 1;
        int mid = values.Length / 2;
        int maxDepth = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Sort(lo, mid, hi, maxDepth);

        End = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
    private void Sort(int lo, int mid, int hi, int maxDepth)
    {
       if (hi - lo < 16)
            InsertionSort.Sort(values, lo, hi);
        else if (maxDepth > 0)
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(
                () => Sort(lo, (mid + lo)/2, mid, maxDepth-1),
                () => Sort(mid + 1, (hi + mid)/2, hi, maxDepth-1));
            Merge(lo, mid, hi);

        }
        else
        {
            Sort(lo, (mid + lo)/2, mid, 0);
            Sort(mid + 1, (hi + mid)/2, hi, 0);
            Merge(lo, mid, hi);
        }
    }
```

Concurrency Visualizer shows that, as far as I can see, threads mostly spend their time waiting, syncing and GCing (not enough rep to post a picture).

What can be done to achieve comparable speed with Java fork/join implmentation? Or is .Net Parallel engine by design inefficient for aggresive multithreading (multitasking)?

PS: Java code

```
public class MergeSort extends RecursiveAction
{
public void parallelSort()
{
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = values.length - 1;
    int mid = values.length / 2;
    ForkJoinPool p = new ForkJoinPool();
    MergeSort s = new MergeSort(lo, mid, hi);
    try
    {
        p.invoke(s);
        p.shutdown();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void compute()
{
    if (hi - lo > 16)
    {
        invokeAll(
                new MergeSort(lo, (mid + lo)/2, mid),
                new MergeSort(mid + 1, (hi + mid)/2, hi));

        merge(lo, mid, hi);
    }
    else
        ElementarySort.insertionSort(values, lo, hi);

}
}
```

Update 1:
interesting, a bottom-up implementation shows inverse results: .Net's Parallel.For() shines and Java's ExecutorService.InvokeAll(): 4 sec vs 193 sec to sort a 256Mb file. Dunno, maybe I'm doing something wrong.
Java code:

```
public void parallelBottomUpSort() throws Exception
{
    ExecutorService p = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);


    for (int sz = 1; sz < values.length; sz *= 2)
    {
        int N = (int) Math.ceil((double) values.length / (2 * sz));
        System.out.println(N);
        List<MergeSort> ms = new ArrayList<>(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int lo = 2 * sz * i;
            int hi = Math.min(lo + 2 * sz, values.length) - 1;
            int mid = lo + sz - 1;
            ms.add(new MergeSort(values, aux, lo, mid, hi));
        }

        p.invokeAll(ms);
    }
    p.shutdown();
}
```

.Net code:

```
 public void ParallelBottomUpSort()
    {

        for (int sz = 1; sz < values.Length; sz *= 2)
            Parallel.For(0, (int) Math.Ceiling((double) values.Length/(2*sz)), i =>
            {
                int lo = 2 * sz * i;
                int hi = Math.Min(lo + 2 * sz, values.Length) - 1;
                int mid = lo + sz - 1;
                Merge(lo, mid, hi);
            });


    }
```

Looks like .Net's parallel engine is generally more stable. Java's concurrent package has its worst and best cases.

Update 2: compilable sources

```
    class Sort
{
    private int[] values, aux;

     public Sort(int[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
        this.aux = new int[values.Length];
    }

     private unsafe void Merge(int lo, int mid, int hi)
     {
         if (lo == hi)
             return;

         if (mid + 1 <= hi && values[mid] <= values[mid + 1])
             return;

         Buffer.BlockCopy(values, sizeof(int) * lo, aux, sizeof(int) * lo, sizeof(int) * (hi - lo + 1));

         int i = lo;
         int j = mid + 1;

         fixed (int* a = values, b = aux)
         {
             for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
             {
                 if (i > mid)
                     a[k] = b[j++];
                 else if (j > hi)
                     a[k] = b[i++];
                 else if (b[i] < b[j])
                     a[k] = b[i++];
                 else
                     a[k] = b[j++];
             }
         }
     }

     public void ParallelBottomUpSort()
     {
         for (int sz = 1; sz < values.Length; sz *= 2)
             Parallel.For(0, (int)Math.Ceiling((double)values.Length / (2 * sz)), i =>
             {
                 int lo = 2 * sz * i;
                 int hi = Math.Min(lo + 2 * sz, values.Length) - 1;
                 int mid = lo + sz - 1;
                 Merge(lo, mid, hi);
             });

     }

     public void ParallelTopDownSort()
     {
         int lo = 0;
         int hi = values.Length - 1;
         int mid = values.Length / 2;
         int maxDepth = (int)Math.Log(Environment.ProcessorCount, 2);
         ParallelTopDownSort(lo, mid, hi, maxDepth);

     }

     private void ParallelTopDownSort(int lo, int mid, int hi, int maxDepth)
     {
         if (hi - lo < 16)
             InsertionSort.Sort(values, lo, hi);
         else if (maxDepth > 0)
         {
             Parallel.Invoke(
                 () => ParallelTopDownSort(lo, (mid + lo) / 2, mid, maxDepth - 1),
                 () => ParallelTopDownSort(mid + 1, (hi + mid) / 2, hi, maxDepth - 1));
             Merge(lo, mid, hi);

         }
         else
         {
             ParallelTopDownSort(lo, (mid + lo) / 2, mid, 0);
             ParallelTopDownSort(mid + 1, (hi + mid) / 2, hi, 0);
             Merge(lo, mid, hi);
         }
     }

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // path to file to be sorted
        String path = args[0];

        Console.WriteLine("Reading file");
        int[] values;

        // Loading file
        var loadStart = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        long intCount = (new FileInfo(path)).Length / 4;
        values = new int[intCount];
        MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path);
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor mma = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
        byte* ptr = (byte*) 0;
        mma.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref ptr);
        Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(ptr), values, 0, (int) intCount);
        var loadEnd = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded in " + (loadEnd - loadStart) / (10000) + " ms");

        // Sorting
        Console.WriteLine("Sorting " + values.Length + " ints");
        Sort ms = new Sort(values);
        var start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        ms.ParallelBottomUpSort();
        var end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Console.WriteLine("Done sorting");
        Console.WriteLine((end - start) / (1000 * 10000));
    }


}
```

Comment: Post image(If you feel that will make it easy to understand) in any fileshare website and post the link here, I'll update the question for you.

Comment: Don't use `DateTime.Now` to measure performance. Try the `Stopwatch` instead. Also, please provide the Java version - without it it's hard to compare anything.

Comment: public link to Concurrency Visualizer image, feel free to post it here: http://yadi.sk/d/ykLwD4STNC8fV

Comment: Thanks for the Java code. Could please reverify your results using `Stopwatch`?

Comment: Also be sure to test a release build and run without the debugger attached (i.e. from the command line, or by pressing Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio). A debug build or (especially) running with the debugger attached will give very different results. Not 10x, though. There has to be a fundamental problem somewhere in your .NET implementation or in the .NET runtime (I'd suspect the former) to make that kind of difference.

Comment: You use the number of processors as `maxDepth` , shouldn't you take the 2-log of the number of processors?

Comment: Changed to int maxDepth = (int) Math.Log(Environment.ProcessorCount ,2);  No difference.

Comment: Can you post a compilable version of the .net code? | @BartoszKP `DateTime.UtcNow` only deviates by ~16ms, since we're talking about several seconds, `StopWatch` will make no difference. Using `StopWatch` is only necessary for processes taking less than a second.